# Wp7, C# Navigate when download is completed in viewModel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, viewmodel

So, I am making an app for wp7.
To keep it simple, these are my files:

- LoginPage.xaml (the starup page)
- MainPage.xaml
- MainViewModel.cs
- ItemViewModel.cs

In MainViewModel.cs I included the folowing function:

```
private void DownloadItems()
    {
        string key = this.User.Key;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += callback;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/items?key=" + key)); //JSON
    }
```

and the callback function:

```
private void callback(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            List<ItemViewModel> col = Deserialize_ItemViewModel(e.Result); // deserialize JSON to List<ItemViewModel>
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(col);
            ItemDB.Sponsors.InsertAllOnSubmit(col);
            ItemDB.SubmitChanges();
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
            // ???
        }
    }
```

When the user logs in the login will be processed and when everything is ok DownloadItems will be called which is using the freshly set User.Key.

What I need is to show a ProgressIndicator while the download is occuring and when the download is completed and processed I want to navigate to MainPage.xaml, which will be ready by that time.

I hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would try to solve it differently. Let your LoginPage only handle the login, then you re-direct to your main page.

In your view model, for the main page, you create a bool property called something like `Loading`, which you can set to true during your async call. Bind this to the visible property of the progress bar so it shows when `Loading` is true, use a converter to handle bool -> visible. When the data is loaded you just set the `Loading` to false which will result in the progress bar disappearing. At the same time you bind the visible property of the control/view to `Loading` as well, but this will use a different converter that is the inverted value of the converter for the progress bar.

Hope that will help.

**UPDATE:** I missed that you already have a `IsDataLoaded`, is that on your view model? The converter should look something like:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
               CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is bool && parameter != null)
        {
            var bValue = (bool) value;
            var visibility = (Visibility)Enum.Parse(
            typeof (Visibility), parameter.ToString(),true);
            if (bValue) return visibility;
            return visibility == 
            Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                   CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsDownloading, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Visible}"
```

Example code is taken from: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/11/converter-for-showinghiding-silverlight.html

Comment: I think that will work for my app, but do you know if I can make a call to a non-static function (the navigation function) from my viewmodel or when this variable updates?

Comment: See the other answer by Pavan for how to make a call on your UI thread from a background thread. But I don't think you need it if you use the solution I provided for you.

Comment: @Qurben, you shouldn't do that in the viewmodel, that is, call the navigation function. The viewmodel has nothing to do with navigation, it is a model for the view. The viewmodel should just flag, notify property changeed, that something has changed to the surroundings then it is up to the surroundings to act on that change. The best flow is probably: Navigate to page and show temporary view until data is loaded. When data is loaded show the expected view.

Comment: Well, with navigation function I mean tell the loginpage that the download is finished and it is okay to proceed to the next page. I it possible to set some kind of deamon function which will proceed when a certain variable becomes true? Without hanging te ui Thread?

Comment: but that is my point, let the login page handle the login and let the next page handle the data related stuff. That will also make it better if you navigate back into your application using the back button.

Comment: Ok, I understand, just navigate when the login finished(handled within Loginpage.xaml) and then navigating to main and then wait for the data to load into the listbox. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Exactly, think it will solve a lot of problem for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

when you update UI in any asynchronous, then you use Dispatcher in the following way

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate

{

 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Folder/pagename.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

});
```

I think it hepls to you.

Comment: I know I can do that from my callback function in the page itself, but I cannot use the Dispatcher from my viewmodel. I think I will just move all the asynchronous stuff to the page, because that is much easier.